# angular select and ng-option binding

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have problem to make ng-option working. 
I have a value alarm.type that I want a list of option gain by $scope.weekTypes.

Here what I tryed so far:

```
        $scope.weekTypes = ["null", "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "Friday", "saturday", "Week", "Week end", "All days"];

<div class="AL_box" ng-repeat="alarm in alarms">
<label for="type"> Type: </label>
<select name="type" ng-model="SelectType" ng-option="weekType as alarm.Type for weekType in weekTypes">
</select>
```

Comment: Please explain better your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asume that alarm.Type has the selected value for this alarm. First of all you have a mistake, `ng-option`doesn't exists, is `ng-options` and you have to define the select model as `alarm.Type` because this will be where the data will be binded.

The result is:

```
<select name="type" ng-model="alarm.Type" ng-options="weekType as weekType for weekType in weekTypes">
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hjr8ozc/3/)

Comment: Thanks. working perfectly ! ng-options is really tricky to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, a couple of things you're doing wrong here:

1. what's declared in the `as ...` is what the option will **show** so it can be clicked: it needs to be `weekType`.
2. if you want the `select` element to change the `alarm.type` attribute, it's your **ngModel** that needs to be bound to `alarm.type`
3. you used `ng-option` while you actually want `ng-options` with an **s**.

Here's a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v35h4ko0/) you can use for reference :)